Sheet component won't close after being opened even with open and onOpenChange props
I have this component, It's a shadcn/ui sheet component that I want to make it open and close when the button is clicked, by button I mean the one that has the onClick event and takes the toggleOpen function, but once the sheet is opened it won't close until I click outside the Sheet or I press the close button inside the SheetContent.
Here is the code to the component:
import {
    Sheet,
    SheetContent,
    SheetDescription,
    SheetHeader,
    SheetTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/sheet";
import { HamburgerMenu } from "./HamburgerMenu";
import { useState } from "react";

const Sidebar = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const toggleOpen = () => {
        setOpen((prev) => !prev);
    };

    return (
        <Sheet open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
            <button onClick={toggleOpen} className="p-0 flex border-0 cursor-pointer bg-transparent ">
                <HamburgerMenu open={open} />
            </button>
            <SheetContent className="top-[3.5rem]" side={"left"}>
                <SheetHeader>
                    <SheetTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</SheetTitle>
                    <SheetDescription>
                        This action cannot be undone. This will permanently
                        delete your account and remove your data from our
                        servers.
                    </SheetDescription>
                </SheetHeader>
            </SheetContent>
        </Sheet>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;

Things I tried:

When I console log the value of the "open" state before and after the setOpen action, it always shows me false in the console, even though it should be toggled (from true to false and vice versa) when the button is clicked, and I don't seem to find where is the problem.

I tried to put the put the button inside the SheetTrigger component and give it the asChild prop but it still didn't work.

I also tried a ternary condition, when the open state is false, the button will be inside the SheetTrigger component, and when it's true I put it inside the SheetClose Component, the only problem is that, the HamburgerMenu I created inside the button which is an animated svg disappears and a another cross svg takes it place, which I think comes standard inside the SheetClose component.



That's a limitation by RadixUI - the headless UI behind shadcn. When the dialog (Sheet component is a dialog) is open, every element in page outside the <DialogContent /> (<SheetContent />) is not accessible exept <DialogTrigger /> (<SheetTrigger />).
For your information, You can use both <SheetTrigger /> with a controlled sheet.
const Sidebar = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <Sheet open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
            <SheetTrigger className="p-0 flex border-0 cursor-pointer bg-transparent ">
                <HamburgerMenu open={open} />
            </SheetTrigger>
            <SheetContent className="top-[3.5rem]" side={"left"}>
                <SheetHeader>
                    <SheetTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</SheetTitle>
                    <SheetDescription>
                        This action cannot be undone. This will permanently
                        delete your account and remove your data from our
                        servers.
                    </SheetDescription>
                </SheetHeader>
            </SheetContent>
        </Sheet>
    );
};

This way, the <SheetTrigger /> will control opening and closing the dialog. and you still have access to the state to pass to your <HamburgerMenu />. If possible, you can also utilise [data-state="open"] attribute in <SheetTrigger /> to apply custom styles to the icon.

First, thanks for your feedback Ahmed, I appreciate it,
I already know most of what you said and I tried this actually but it didn't work, once the sheet is opened it can't be closed unless you click on the <SheetClose /> or the <SheetOverlay> components.
Looking at the radix docs, the [data-state] attribute switches between "open" or "closed" based on the state of the sheet, but I don't know how to directly play with this attribute since it isn't provided as prop but just in the styles. Whereas in my case, I want to control it on the click of the button or <SheetTrigger />.
